# Composite C1 - Multiple domains & sites in one Composite C1 instance

Tags: c1-cms

I am newish to Composite C1.

I need 5 sites, all sharing HTML & CSS layout & code - but all must have different contant.

They each need their own domain:
Domain1.com
Domain2.com
...

What is the best way to set this up?

I setup 1 - and I add another website and it makes is a 'subsite' of the original one in my dev IIS - eg:

First site URL: Domain1.com/mypage
Second site URL: Domain1.com/another page

How do I force the second site to use a new domain?

Also are there host headers? How can I route traffic appropriately to each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composite C1 has a built-in URL/Hostname configuration component (System / URL Configuration / Hostnames)

http://docs.composite.net/Configuration/UrlConfiguration/Hostnames

In short, you should:

1. have valid domain names bound on IIS to your C1 instance
2. map each domain name (hostname) to a corresponding subsite / language version of your susbsite in the C1 Console (System / URL Configuration / Hostnames)

Comment: thanks! How do I bind a valid domain names - just list them all under host headers?

Comment: I just listed all domains in IIS using host headers - works really well. Thanks.